# $near $unwind mongodb geospatial

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, mongodb-java

I have a Educational Intitution document which looks like this:

`{ name: ..., addresses: [{state: ..., locs: []}, ...], courses: [...] }`

Where locs is where my geospatial points are.

To execute a `$near` command I need to `$unwind` addresses because I can have an Educational Institution in many points.

My current method looks like this:

```
public BasicDBList findByCoordinates(double latitude, double longitude){

    BasicDBObject cmdBody = new BasicDBObject("aggregate", "EducationalInstitution");

    List<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    BasicDBObject projectParams = new BasicDBObject();
    projectParams.put("name", 1);
    projectParams.put("addresses.state", 1);
    projectParams.put("addresses.locs", 1);
    projectParams.put("courses", 1);

    BasicDBObject geoParams = new BasicDBObject();
    geoParams.put("$near", new double[] { latitude, longitude });
    geoParams.put("$maxDistance", 50/111.12);

    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", projectParams));
    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$addresses"));

    cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline);
    cmdBody.put("$addresses.locs", geoParams);

    return (BasicDBList) getDatastore().getDB().command(cmdBody).get("result");
}
```

I tried near method from morphia

```
createQuery().field("addresses.locs").near(latitude, longitude, 50/111.12);
```

However it returns all addresses that I want unwinded, I just need the address which are near from some point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. First I tried use $match and $near, however, without success.

Then I read about $geoNear aggregation and tried put as the last parameter of my pipeline, however, according MongoDB page: "You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline."

I was in doubt about $unwind that I needed, but, I found a parameter which helps me in an array localization.

My shell code:

`db.EducationalInstitution.aggregate( 
      {$geoNear: {near: [-15.795758,-47.892312], maxDistance: 50/111.12, distanceField: "addresses.calculated", includeLocs: "addresses.locs", niqueDocs: true}},
      {$project: {"name": 1, "addresses.state": 1, "addresses.locs": 1}}
    );`

My Java code:

`public BasicDBList findByCoordinates(double longitude, double latitude){`

```
    BasicDBObject cmdBody = new BasicDBObject("aggregate", "EducationalInstitution");

    List<BasicDBObject> pipeline = new ArrayList<BasicDBObject>();

    BasicDBObject geoNearParams = new BasicDBObject();
    geoNearParams.put("near", new double[] {longitude, latitude,});
    geoNearParams.put("maxDistance", 50/111.12);
    geoNearParams.put("distanceField", "addresses.calculated");
    geoNearParams.put("includeLocs", "addresses.locs");
    geoNearParams.put("niqueDocs", true);

    BasicDBObject projectParams = new BasicDBObject();
    projectParams.put("name", 1);
    projectParams.put("addresses.state", 1);
    projectParams.put("addresses.locs", 1);
    projectParams.put("courses", 1);

    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$geoNear", geoNearParams));
    pipeline.add(new BasicDBObject("$project", projectParams));

    cmdBody.put("pipeline", pipeline); 

    if( !getDatastore().getDB().command(cmdBody).ok() ){

        throw new MongoException(getDatastore().getDB().command(cmdBody).getErrorMessage());
    }

    return (BasicDBList) getDatastore().getDB().command(cmdBody).get("result");
}
```

Thx